# How to see problems with the Kattis problem: Elevator Trouble?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to solve the Kattis problem "Elevator Trouble" in C# https://open.kattis.com/problems/elevatortrouble for some time,
but I keep missing something since I never pass all the tests in my solution.

**Test cases given (and executed successfully)**

Input: 10 1 10 2 1,
my output: 6,
expected output: 6

Input: 100 2 1 1 0,
my output: use the stairs,
expected output: use the stairs

The test cases that are provided in the Kattis problem passes (see above), and give the expected output

Here is the solution which has been most successful:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var values = input.Split(" ");
        var output = NumberOfButtonPress(values);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    public static string NumberOfButtonPress(string[] values)
    {
        int floors = int.Parse(values[0]);
        int start = int.Parse(values[1]);
        int goal = int.Parse(values[2]);
        int up = int.Parse(values[3]);
        int down = int.Parse(values[4]);

        var buttonPresses = goal - (start + (up * up) - (down * down)); 

        return buttonPresses >= 0 && buttonPresses < floors ? buttonPresses.ToString() : "use the stairs";
    }
}
```

Comment: could give of  some good (input, output) and some (input, false output) -> result waited..

Comment: As given in the problem, one example was:

input: 10 1 10 2 1,
my output: 6,
expected output: 6.

Other given test cases was not provided, and no error logs given

Comment: You only provided test cases that succeed. But as you claim that other test cases fail, you should show these, too.

Comment: This is due to the Kattis problem (as linked to in the question) has more test-cases than are given in the example. There for me asking for help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is little more complex than a simple collection of up,down,up,down or down,up,down..

**The first step:**

Check if the solution is possible with the parameters given,

**The second step:**

find the algorithm..

*Just because the current stage is lower than the target does not mean that the best solution is to start by pressing the up button.*

**EDIT**
Solution validated on https://open.kattis.com/

there a solution using the [Breadth-first_search or BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm: the objective is to explore all possibilities (to avoid to loop indefinitily) and see if a solution exists or not.. (*maybe not the best solution*)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int f;
        public static int s;
        public static int g;
        public static int u;
        public static int d;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (values.Length != 5 || values.Any(x => !int.TryParse(x, out int value)))
                    continue;
                var intgs = values.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

                if (!intgs.All(x => x >= 0 && x <= 1000000))
                    continue;
                if (intgs[1] > intgs[0] ||
                    intgs[2] > intgs[0] || 
                    intgs[1] < 1 || intgs[2] < 1)
                    continue;

                f = intgs[0];
                s = intgs[1];
                g = intgs[2];
                u = intgs[3];
                d = intgs[4];

                var result = NumberOfButtonPress();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }

        public static string NumberOfButtonPress()
        {
            var result = BFS();
            if (result < 0)
                return "use the stairs";
            else
                return ($"{result}");

        }

        private static int BFS()
        {
            Queue<(int, int)> q = new Queue<(int, int)>();
            HashSet<int> seen = new HashSet<int>();

            Action<int, int, int> move = (int currFloor, int numSteps, int location) =>
            {
                int nextFloor = currFloor + location;
                if (!seen.Contains(nextFloor))
                {
                    q.Enqueue((nextFloor, numSteps + 1));
                    seen.Add(nextFloor);
                }
            };

            q.Enqueue((s, 0));
            seen.Add(s);

            while (q.Count > 0)
            {
                (int currFloor, int numSteps) = q.Dequeue();

                if (currFloor == g)
                {
                    return numSteps;
                }

                if (u + currFloor <= g)
                    move(currFloor, numSteps, u);
                else if (currFloor - d >= 1)
                    move(currFloor, numSteps, -d);
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. You can optimized it further:  Define Action<int,int, int> move = (int currFloor, int numSteps,int location) => {   
    int nextFloor = currFloor + location;
                if (!seen.Contains(nextFloor))
                {
                    q.Enqueue((nextFloor, numSteps + 1));
                    seen.Add(nextFloor);
                }
  }; inside BFS and call it :   if (up + currFloor <= nbfloors)
    move(currFloor,numSteps,up);           
            else if (currFloor - down >= 1)
    move(currFloor,numSteps,-down);

Comment: Thank you both, for contributing to my learning. It was really helpful getting the input of the BFS-algorithm, which helped alot to solve my problem.
The second part, that did help solving this problem was input validation, which in my solution was not considerd at all.

Comment: @Emi i have a solution to simulate  lot of test which simulates Console.read. (using Console.SetIn and console.SetOut..i can simulate multines or one line    with the match of result waites.....but open a new question for that